# Custom x-headers are removed after the message is saved in Outlook desktop

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

I've been working on an Outlook add-in which inserts custom x-headers based on interaction with a user. Outlook Web Application works fine. I encountered a problem when these custom x-headers disappeared from the message in Outlook Desktop (Windows 10 and macOS Monterey version 12.2).

The environment info:

Windows 10 Pro version is 21H2, OS build 19044.1469

Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019

Microsoft® Outlook® 2019 MSO (Version 2110 Build 16.0.14527.20234) 32-bit

macOS Monterey version 12.2

Microsoft Outlook for Mac Version 16.53 (21091200)

To make sure that the insertion of the headers was successful and to pinpoint the moment when the headers disappear I performed the Add-in logic manually by using the OutlookSpy tool on Windows10. The result was the same and it looks like the headers were removed by the save message operation.

The details are provided below:

1. Open Compose, type subject, save message using ctrl+S or pressing button with disk image. Message created in the draft folder
2. Navigate to the message in the draft folder. Open OutlookSpy EWS Request pad and send the following EWS GetItem request to find a ChangeKey. Current Item Id is provided in the EWS Request pad

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetItem
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
      xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>        
      </ItemShape>
      <ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGQ2NjU3NGQ2LTFjMGItNGM1ZC1hMjMzLTM1YjUzYzYyZDY3NABGAAAAAABOqCUOqEzcRIky8XqnjNqxBwCNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AAAAAAEPAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrvkZMAAA="/>
      </ItemIds>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

3. The response message returned the current ChangeKey

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="V2018_01_08" MinorBuildNumber="15" MajorBuildNumber="5081" MinorVersion="20" MajorVersion="15"/>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
          <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:Items>
            <t:Message>
              <t:ItemId ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrDEAU" Id="AAMkAGQ2NjU3NGQ2LTFjMGItNGM1ZC1hMjMzLTM1YjUzYzYyZDY3NABGAAAAAABOqCUOqEzcRIky8XqnjNqxBwCNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AAAAAAEPAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrvkZMAAA="/>
            </t:Message>
          </m:Items>
        </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:GetItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

4. Send the following EWS UpdateItem request to set a custom x-header. Use the ChangeKey received in the previous step

```
<soap:Body>
    <UpdateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" ConflictResolution="AlwaysOverwrite" 
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <ItemChanges>
        <t:ItemChange>
          <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGQ2NjU3NGQ2LTFjMGItNGM1ZC1hMjMzLTM1YjUzYzYyZDY3NABGAAAAAABOqCUOqEzcRIky8XqnjNqxBwCNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AAAAAAEPAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrvkZMAAA="
                    ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrDEAU"/>
          <t:Updates>
            <t:SetItemField>
              <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="x-custom-header1" PropertyType="String"/>
              <t:Message>
                <t:ExtendedProperty>
                  <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="x-custom-header1" PropertyType="String"/>
                  <t:Value>yes</t:Value>
                </t:ExtendedProperty>
              </t:Message>
            </t:SetItemField>
          </t:Updates>
        </t:ItemChange>
      </ItemChanges>
    </UpdateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

5. The response to the UpdateItem request shows Success/NoError with 0 conflicts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="V2018_01_08" MinorBuildNumber="15" MajorBuildNumber="5081" MinorVersion="20" MajorVersion="15"/>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <m:UpdateItemResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:UpdateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
          <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:Items>
            <t:Message>
              <t:ItemId ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrDECs" Id="AAMkAGQ2NjU3NGQ2LTFjMGItNGM1ZC1hMjMzLTM1YjUzYzYyZDY3NABGAAAAAABOqCUOqEzcRIky8XqnjNqxBwCNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AAAAAAEPAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrvkZMAAA="/>
            </t:Message>
          </m:Items>
          <m:ConflictResults>
            <t:Count>0</t:Count>
          </m:ConflictResults>
        </m:UpdateItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:UpdateItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

6. Send the following EWS GetItem request to check that the custom x-header was set up. Use the ChangeKey received in the previous step

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetItem
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
      xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="x-custom-header1" PropertyType="String" />
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </ItemShape>
      <ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGQ2NjU3NGQ2LTFjMGItNGM1ZC1hMjMzLTM1YjUzYzYyZDY3NABGAAAAAABOqCUOqEzcRIky8XqnjNqxBwCNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AAAAAAEPAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrvkZMAAA="
                  ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrDECs" />
      </ItemIds>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

7. The GetItem response contains the custom x-header which was set up in the step 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="V2018_01_08" MinorBuildNumber="15" MajorBuildNumber="5081" MinorVersion="20" MajorVersion="15"/>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
          <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:Items>
            <t:Message>
              <t:ItemId ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrDECs" Id="AAMkAGQ2NjU3NGQ2LTFjMGItNGM1ZC1hMjMzLTM1YjUzYzYyZDY3NABGAAAAAABOqCUOqEzcRIky8XqnjNqxBwCNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AAAAAAEPAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrvkZMAAA="/>
              <t:Subject>test ews 3</t:Subject>
              <t:ExtendedProperty>
                <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyType="String" PropertyName="x-custom-header1" DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders"/>
                <t:Value>yes</t:Value>
              </t:ExtendedProperty>
            </t:Message>
          </m:Items>
        </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:GetItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

8. In the compose window type something in the message body and save the message using ctrl+S or pressing button with disk image
9. The save operation in the previous step will modify the item ChangeKey. Send the following GetItem request to get a new ChangeKey

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetItem
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
      xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
      </ItemShape>
      <ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGQ2NjU3NGQ2LTFjMGItNGM1ZC1hMjMzLTM1YjUzYzYyZDY3NABGAAAAAABOqCUOqEzcRIky8XqnjNqxBwCNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AAAAAAEPAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrvkZMAAA=" />
      </ItemIds>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

10. The successful response is returning the new ChangeKey

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="V2018_01_08" MinorBuildNumber="15" MajorBuildNumber="5081" MinorVersion="20" MajorVersion="15"/>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
          <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:Items>
            <t:Message>
              <t:ItemId ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrDEDV" Id="AAMkAGQ2NjU3NGQ2LTFjMGItNGM1ZC1hMjMzLTM1YjUzYzYyZDY3NABGAAAAAABOqCUOqEzcRIky8XqnjNqxBwCNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AAAAAAEPAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrvkZMAAA="/>
            </t:Message>
          </m:Items>
        </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:GetItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

11. Send the following EWS GetItem request to check that the custom x-header is still in place. Use the ChangeKey received in the previous step

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetItem
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
      xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="x-custom-header1" PropertyType="String" />
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </ItemShape>
      <ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGQ2NjU3NGQ2LTFjMGItNGM1ZC1hMjMzLTM1YjUzYzYyZDY3NABGAAAAAABOqCUOqEzcRIky8XqnjNqxBwCNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AAAAAAEPAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrvkZMAAA="
                  ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrDEDV" />
      </ItemIds>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

12. The received GetItem response doesn't contain our custom x-header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="V2018_01_08" MinorBuildNumber="15" MajorBuildNumber="5081" MinorVersion="20" MajorVersion="15"/>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
          <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:Items>
            <t:Message>
              <t:ItemId ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrDEDV" Id="AAMkAGQ2NjU3NGQ2LTFjMGItNGM1ZC1hMjMzLTM1YjUzYzYyZDY3NABGAAAAAABOqCUOqEzcRIky8XqnjNqxBwCNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AAAAAAEPAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADrvkZMAAA="/>
              <t:Subject>test ews 3</t:Subject>
            </t:Message>
          </m:Items>
        </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:GetItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you tried to open a support case with MS? Have you checked any other Exchange server version? Is it specific to a particular Exchange version?

Comment: Try using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) instead.

Comment: If the picture has not been changed I'd recommend opening a support case with MS.

Comment: Sorry, I tested with the only one Exchange server version.

Comment: In general, if you use EWS to modify an item on the server, then save/send the item on the client, the client will blow away the changes on the server when it tries to resolve conflicts. Most solutions should do everything on the client or on the server to avoid these kinds of issues. Does the Internet Headers Office.js API help you at all?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.internetheaders?view=outlook-js-preview

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Thanks for response. Client should not blow all server changes, instead, it should do "autoResolve" with request of latest "changeKey". At least this is what Web client does as it works fine. We have C++ solution as well, which uses "Imessage" and "MailItem" at the same time, this should not be the problem. Are you certain about your statement? We still will be opening the case, but your input very valuable. Yes, we will use Office API facility, but as you know the minimum requirement set is very high (1.8), we would like to support older clients as well.

Comment: Outlook Desktop does not have AutoResolve in mapisync. It is expected that different clients behave differently. IMessage vs Mailitem also should be client communication. 
As mentioned above, we recommend doing everything on the client or all on the server.